# Question About Heists Replay

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have completed gta v fleeca heist with random players my question is how to earn criminal mastermind achievement. I now have 4 trusted friends but how to do it again from start and earn 12 million I have already done fleeca job heist.

Comment: You have to start it again with your trusted friends, CM achivement works only if you do all the heists with same team members

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you want the Criminal Mastermind Challenge, where you need to play all of the Heists and Setups from the Heists Update with the same team, in hard without loosing any lives for 10 millions for each player.

Let's call your friends A, B, C and D. For the Criminal Mastermind, you need to restart all of the heists that you have completed. If you have any heist active, you would need to cancel it or complete it and then start with The Fleeca Job in order (you can call Lester to replay a heist).

The correct order for the Heists and their setups is:

- The Fleeca Job: A and B in one group, C and D in another group
- The Prison Break: All players
- The Humane Labs Raid: All players
- Series A Funding: All players
- The Pacific Standard: All Players

Due to The Fleeca Job, it works a bit differently due to being a 2 player heist instead of 4. For it, you need to split in two teams, let's say players A and B in one team and players C and D in another team. They need to complete the Fleeca heist in their groups of two to then go ahead and join the 4 for The Prison Break.

If you have not completed the previous Bonus Rewards, then you can also probably get this ones:

- All in Order Challenge (all setups and finales in order)
- Loyalty Challenge (all setups and finales with the same team)

And if you are on PS4/PS5, Xbox One/Series X|S or PC, you can also probably take this one if you want:

- Another Perspective Challenge (all setups and finales in first person, needs to be forced by the host)